# How can i handle multiple submit button in while loop,Every Item have unique id but

Tags: php, while-loop, submit

How can i handle multiple submit button in while loop,Every Item have unique id but buttons are generated with while loop so every button have same name and when i submit the form it can't submit

Comment: Hi, could you please provide more context: Which language/framework are you using? Also, please use the technology you are using (javascript? html?) as the tags. Thank you!

Comment: I am using php.

Comment: I am using PHP language. I am working on the form to put the form data into the database,I am using multiple submit button in my form,buttons are generated with the help of while loop so every button have same name so when i submit the form every submit button have been submitted so how can i prevent other buttons ko stop submitting except one.